# Plantronics BackBeat GO 2 can't connect with Dell M6800 even pairing successfully

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

This problem drives me crazy, I did everything I can..

The headset "Plantronics BackBeat GO 2" can connect with my iPad, my Android phone and my Lenovo laptop, however, it can't work with my laptop DELL M6800!

Pairing is successful, drivers can be installed successfully, but when I'm trying to connect the headset, it always says:
    `Error connecting to headset. Please retry this operation.`

[image]

[image]

[image]

I really appreciate it if you can give me some advices. thanks!

Comment: Try to update your PC Bluetooth Device drivers to latest version.

Comment: Reinstall OS solved the problem, it turns out there are some other drivers conflicting with bluetooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by uninstall chip driver and reinstall with the proper one.

Answer (score 1):

download and install PlantronicsHubInstaller-3.4 and PlantronicsSetup once you do this and shows  online you go to the show bluetooth devices. click trouble shot and let it do drivers again it will work . i have a dell n5110. by the way im using the same headphones you have. so personal experenice and exact things you been doing